# monet db user / role / database / tables

Tags: monetdb

```
monetdb create ebi_dwh  
monetdb release ebi_dwh
```

```
CREATE ROLE "ebi_reader";
CREATE ROLE "ebi_writer";
```

```
CREATE SCHEMA "ebi" AUTHORIZATION ebi_reader;
CREATE SCHEMA "ebi_data" AUTHORIZATION ebi_writer;
```

```
CREATE USER "ebi" WITH PASSWORD 'pwd' NAME 'data_views user' SCHEMA "ebi" DEFAULT ROLE "ebi_reader";
CREATE USER "ebi_data" WITH PASSWORD 'pwd' NAME 'data_tables user' SCHEMA "ebi_data" DEFAULT ROLE "ebi_writer";
```

```
GRANT ebi_reader TO ebi;
GRANT ebi_reader TO ebi_data;
GRANT ebi_writer TO ebi_data;
```

```
mclient -u ebi_data -d ebi_dwh
password:
Welcome to mclient, the MonetDB/SQL interactive terminal (Dec2023)
Database: MonetDB v11.49.1 (Dec2023), 'mapi:monetdb://:50000/ebi_dwh'
FOLLOW US on https://twitter.com/MonetDB or https://github.com/MonetDB/MonetDB
Type \q to quit, \? for a list of available commands
auto commit mode: on
sql>create table ebi.test_via_ebidata (id int, name varchar(5));
CREATE TABLE: insufficient privileges for user 'ebi_data' in schema 'ebi'
```

Hello,
What am I doing wrong? I thought ebi_data is allowed to create tables in the ebi schema because I granted

```
GRANT ebi_reader TO ebi_data
```

What did I overlook?"
Thank you in advance Br

I thought ebi_data is allowed to create tables in the ebi schema because I granted

```
GRANT ebi_reader TO ebi_data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to set the role of `ebi_data` to `ebi_reader`:

```
$ mclient -d ebi_dwh -u ebi_data
...
sql>create table ebi.test_via_ebidata (id int, name varchar(5));
CREATE TABLE: insufficient privileges for user 'ebi_data' in schema 'ebi'
sql>set role ebi_reader;
operation successful
sql>create table ebi.test_via_ebidata (id int, name varchar(5));
operation successful
```

You need to be an owner of a schema to have the privilege to create a table. the owner of the schema `ebi` is the role `ebi_reader`.

When user `ebi_data` logs in, the user assumes its default role `ebi_writer`. To create a table in the schema `ebi`, `ebi_data` needs to switch its role to `ebi_reader`.

PS> I guess there was a typo in your query.  I changed it into `CREATE SCHEMA "ebi" AUTHORIZATION ebi_reader;`

Comment: Hello Jennie, thank you very much for your answer. I'm sorry I can't vote the answer up. br

Comment: Is the normal procedure to load data into MonetDB with monetdb-user and grant permissions only after loading?

Comment: sorry, didn't see your question earlier.  I think it totally depends on your use case: when do you want to let which user have what kinds of access to which part of the data.